# For APNS Website is asking for APNS certificate in the form text input

Tags: ios, xcode

I need to get alert when i go near-by iBeacon, for this i am using third party iBeacon Management Service namely by https://admin.lighthousebeacon.io/applications/541190913a9c4d2b34ecea3c . they are asking
for APNS certificate and they have given me textfield for certificate . how to supply certificate in the form of text to them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just follow [raywenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1) tutorial to create your APNS certificates and after that follow [OnGitHub](https://github.com/inlight-media/lighthouse-ios) topic name "Generating Push Notification Certificates for Admin Portal", it will guide you how convert your certificate into text fromat.